# SWT: error in changing check box value programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

My intention is to change the value of check box and based on a condition that is set through the drop box. I am stuck at this place. But this is not working as expected.

```
public void notifyChanged(IPropertyEditor otherEditor) {
    ConnectionType changedConnectionType = getConnectionType(otherEditor);
    if (!ConnectionType.UNDEFINED.equals(changedConnectionType)) {
        connectionType = changedConnectionType;
        updateChange(false);
    }
    if (button != null && !ConnectionType.UNDEFINED.equals(connectionType)) {
        button.setEnabled(canEnable(connectionType));
        updateChange(true);
    }
}


private void updateChange(boolean selected){
    this.selected=selected;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `setSelected(boolean)` method of `Button` to check the check box.

The `setEnabled` call marks the control as enabled or disabled (not usable).

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg, it worked. The button details are stored in IPropertyEditor object which on refreshing worked, with you suggestion,